# Debugging glibc on ARM embedded system

Tags: c, linux, glibc

I've got problem with running Xorg on ARM system. I'm receiving SEGV on Xorg from time to time. After a little investigation (cross gdb) I found out that the stack is currupted so I cannot see the proper call stack of procedures. From the kernel logs I've taken LR register value and it turned out that this address is ok and belongs to glibc. So it means that the last properly invocated procedure is in glibc. At the moment I'm trying do debug glibc, however it is not so easy because printf() and puts() doesn't work.

I modified a little kernel SEGV handler and now I know that the LR is pointing to char_buffer_add_slow() procedure from glibc. This procedure is called from _IO_vscanf() proc.

Is there any method to print some messages from glibc? 
Any other ideas how to debug glibc on ARM?

Comment: Do you have a trace option in your tool chain? If so, put a breakpoint on the SEGV exception code, then simply read the trace to see how you ended up there. It does sound like a stack overflow though, so the calling code is not necessarily the culprit. To solve a stack overflow, you have to review the whole program and look for unnecessary stack use. Large local buffers and software floating point are common causes.

Comment: How can I check if my toolchain has this trace option?

Comment: You would probably know. First of all the CPU needs to support it, meaning Cortex M3 or bigger. Then you'll have some some option in the debugger called instruction trace or similar. Which ARM is this and which debugger are you using?

Comment: It is Cortex A8. I'm using gdb 8.0.1.